# Fill in cells based on the contents of a variable range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

In my spreadsheet, I have a list of data in a column that has item numbers. Given a value (either "'1 Quad" or any value A-D) in an adjacent cell, there should be no rows with repeating item numbers or 8 rows with repeating item numbers respectively in the same column.  If there are more or less than the required amount of item numbers (too many repeating numbers or missed numbers), then I would like the entire variable range of identical item numbers to highlight (which I am simply doing with Fill).

```
   For i = 3 To (mainRow - 1)
    k = i
    j = i
    If Range("G3") = "'1 Quad" Then
        If Range("E" & i).Value > (Range("E" & (i + 1)).Value - 1) Then
            Range("E" & i, "E" & (i + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If Range("E" & i).Value < (Range("E" & (i + 1)).Value - 1) Then
            Range("E" & i, "E" & (i + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    ElseIf Range("G3").Value = "A" Or "B" Or "C" Or "D" Then
        Do
            If Range("E" & j).Value = Range("E" & (j + 1)).Value Then
                j = j + 1
            End If
            If Range("E" & j).Value <> Range("E" & (j + 1)).Value Then
                If j < 8 Then
                    For k = i To j
                        Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Next k
                End If

                If j > 8 Then
                    For k = i To j
                        Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    Next k
                End If
                Exit Do
            End If
        While j < (mainRow - 1)
        i = k
    End If

Next i
```

With This code, I am getting the error "End If without Block If" which does not appear to be the case at all.  If I remove the last "End IF", I receive the "Next without For" error.  Thanks ahead of time for your help.

**I edited the code to include the end ifs and still receiving the same error.

Comment: Your two `If J < 8` and `If J > 8` don't have a closing `End If` I don't think.

Comment: I had them there, and received the same error (just verified it again). They both result in exiting the do loop anyway.

Comment: is anything supposed to happen when J=8?  maybe not, but you had the case when its not 8 covered so I thought I would ask incase you meant a >= or <= instead.

Comment: you will eventually need those endifs back in place.  Every IF statement needs an end if.(with the exception possibly of a single line if).  With your tabbed formatting if you look straight down from your IF statement it should line up with an ENDIF at some point.

Comment: Yes, when j=8, it is supposed to exit the do loop. I moved the two "exit Do" out  of the if statements and put it one level higher.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing 3 End Ifs, and your Do-While syntax is off. Try this instead:

```
    Do While j < (mainRow - 1)
        If Range("E" & j).Value <> Range("E" & (j + 1)).Value Then
            If j < 8 Then
                For k = i To j
                    Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Next k
                Exit Do
            End If
            If j > 8 Then
                For k = i To j
                    Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Next k
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: I put my "end ifs" back in and still am receiving the same error regarding the last "end if" in my original code. Thanks.

Comment: I realized. Check the fix. Not sure if you wanted i=k before Loop

Comment: Do While/loop fixed the issue. Thanks!